# Looking for way to export .dat data with no .ddf files

Tags: btrieve

I have inherited a program called Magic and is version 8.3.  We would like to export the data but I am not sure how to do this.  All the files are in .dat format and appears to need Btrieve. I did contact the Magic company and they say it would be over $5k to do.  I can't believe there isn't an easier way but maybe this is true.

[Magic activity console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzN3N.png)

So above is something I found and can see when people are using the tool.  I can't find anything to allow me to query or look at the data in a formatted way.

End goal is to get data out of this and put into a sql server.

Anyone have any ideas how I can export this?

Comment: if you open one of the .DAT files with a text editor can you see the data or is it all encoded?

Comment: The DAT files are Btrieve files.  They have a specific binary format and while some data (strings) might be readable in a text editor, most (any other binary data like integers or other numbers) won't be readable.

Comment: Here is the top of one of my files [link](http://www.lleemon.com/img/20220406_Magic-Techsche.dat_top.png) @RyDog

Answer (score 0):

The Magic environment used to have a method for creating the DDFs.  I think it is called "DDF Make."  Once you have the DDFs, you will still need a Btrieve / Pervasive / Actian engine to read the files.  If you know the **exact** record structure, you *might* be able to create the DDFs (and table entries) manually through SQL or a DDF Builder tool.